# Welsh letters with circumflex: example - ŷ

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

Can these be input via my Galaxy s4 keyboard?

The example is embraced by Unicode hex `0177` and its capital version `0176`. The Welsh language is not amongst the language options on this device.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with Google's `Gboard` ? This keyboard has support for several languages including Welsh. Simply touch and hold Y : `ŷ`, `Ŷ`

[image]

Comment: You also need to add Cymraeg to the 'phone if not done already, and this means using the All Languages list as Samsung unaccountably doesn't include it in their selective list (in addition to not allowing for it in their own keyboard even if you do add the language to the 'phone).

Comment: P.S. the Google keyboard app is called 'Gboard'.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out